# Working with objects from Global Environment in loops (R)

Tags: r, loops, xlconnect

I am trying to fill an existing sheets in object `wb` (Formal class workbook XLConnect) with data frames from my Global Environment

I have a list of names of my data frames - `dataframe_list`, and a list of sheet names - `sheetsname`, both are character vectors

I have created a loop to fill corresponding sheets in `wb` if the name from my `dataframe_list` and the name of sheet `sheetsname` in `wb` are equal

My problem is, when I am running a loop, in particular `data=dataframe_list[k]`, loop uses a name but not the data frame with corresponding name.

Hope for you help

```
for(k in 1:length(dataframe_list)) {
for(i in 1:length(sheetsname)) {

if (dataframe_list[k]==sheetsname[i]) {
        writeWorksheet(wb,data=dataframe_list[k],sheet=as.character(dataframe_list[k]),startRow = 49,
                       startCol = 3, header = FALSE)

}}
}
```

Comment: @alistaire I think according to OP that it is a vector of data.frame names, not a list of data frames.

Comment: 'get' is woking fine, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return the actual data frame from its name, rather than just the name itself, use `get`.  As in

```
    writeWorksheet(wb, data = get(dataframe_list[k]),
       sheet=as.character(dataframe_list[k]), startRow = 49,
       startCol = 3, header = FALSE)
```

Note, not tested, as this was not a complete reproducible example provided

Answer (score 0):

XLConnect's `writeWorksheet` is vectorized, so you can provide a `list` of `data.frame`s and a vector of sheet names like so:

```
# Collect data.frames in a list
dfs <- lapply(dataframe_list, get)

writeWorksheet(wb, data = dfs, sheet = sheetnames, ...)
```

No need for a for loop here.